# while using after_create (ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I am trying to create a record in ClientUserEmailPreference when an email record is newly created. I tried `after_create` to create a new record whenever new email record is created. But, When I try to create a new email record, it shows `ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation` The following is my email model.

```
class Email < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :email_type
    belongs_to :email_preference_section
    has_many :client_user_email_preferences
    validates :name, allow_blank: false, presence: true
    validates :email_type_id, allow_blank: false, presence: true
    validates :email_preference_section_id, allow_blank: true
    validates :position, allow_blank: false, presence: true

    after_create :set_default_to_client_users

    def set_default_to_client_users
            new_preference = ClientUserEmailPreference.new
            new_preference.client_user_id = that_client_user.id
            new_preference.email_id = self.id
            new_preference.enabled = true
            if self.email_type_id != 1
                new_preference.frequency = "every week"
                new_preference.day_of_the_week = 1
            end
            new_preference.save
    end
end
```

I don't know how to effectively create a row in ClientUserEmailPreference whenever a new email is created

Comment: Rails by default lazy loads application modules/classes in the development environment. My guess is that `ClientUserEmailPreference` is only loaded in when you reference it in your *after_create* callback. The contents of `ClientUserEmailPreference` might have an invalid validation, where you do specify an attribute, but not a validation. Your stack trace should tell you where the exception is produced. Could you add the stack trace to the question?

Comment: I commented out all the validation in ```ClientUserEmailPreference```, still it is not resolved

Comment: That was just a guess. Without stack trace it's hard for us to say what's going wrong.

Comment: The error was in the validation part as u guessed, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably at this line

```
validates :email_preference_section, allow_blank: true
```

Since it's an association, if you want it be optional  remove the above validation and then do this instead

```
belongs_to :email_preference_section, optional: true
```

Also, you don't need this line too since it is enabled by default for foreign keys

```
validates :email_type_id, allow_blank: false, presence: true
```

Give it a try!

Comment: I commented out that validation, now the error is resolved, but ```after_create``` is not invoked, the ClientUserEmailPreferences table remains unchanged.

Comment: It must be invoked, can you change this line `new_preference.save` to this `new_preference.save!` and see if you get any error? Also, is your `Email` record saving in the database?

Comment: Am simply getting ```ROLLBACK```, there is no error logs except that.

Comment: Then your Email record is not saving because of some validation, can you show me how you are saving `Email` in controller

Comment: I am creating new email record in rails console, no controllers are created

Comment: In console to save `Email` can you use `save!` instead of `save` and see what error you are getting

Comment: Still only getting rollback and Email is saved, ClientUserEmailPreference remains untouched

Comment: That's weird, Can you show me what you are trying in console

Comment: ```Email.create(name: "Stack check", email_type_id: 2, email_preference_section_id: 4, position: 4)``` I think this create command is enough to create a new email record, the creation of the new record triggers ```after_create```, fortunately, the triggering is working, but the creation of ClientUserEmailPreference is not happening, instead of that I was getting **ROLLBACK**.

Comment: Ok, can you add ! to create, what is this returning? `Email.create!(name: "Stack check", email_type_id: 2, email_preference_section_id: 4, position: 4)`

Comment: I solved it bro, with the help of ```create!```, there was some validation issues in the ClientUserEmailPreference and after commenting it out, everything is working fine and good as expected, Thanks!

Comment: @MageshBhaskaran Can you please mark this answer as accepted, it encourages us developers to help others.